# Find all values that match a condition and execute function to transform text to columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have no idea how to, but I need to allow the following code to run as long there is an cell that satisfy this condition. I've tried some functions, but none of them worked. Since you fellows, are much wiser than me, I hope that you could help me.
The only requirement is that the condition to search must start with "08", and the function let me transform text to columns.

Tks in Advance

```
Sub getDataProperly()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'

    Cells.Find(What:="08*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(10, 2), Array(15, 2), Array(19, 2), Array(27, 2), _
        Array(31, 2), Array(39, 2), Array(43, 2), Array(51, 2), Array(55, 2), Array(63, 2), Array( _
        67, 2), Array(75, 2), Array(79, 2), Array(87, 2), Array(91, 2), Array(99, 2), Array(103, 2), _
        Array(111, 2), Array(115, 2), Array(123, 2), Array(127, 2), Array(135, 2), Array(139, 2), _
        Array(147, 2), Array(151, 2), Array(159, 2), Array(163, 2), Array(171, 2), Array(175, 2), _
        Array(183, 2), Array(187, 2), Array(195, 2), Array(199, 2), Array(207, 2), Array(211, 2), _
        Array(219, 2), Array(223, 2), Array(231, 2), Array(235, 2), Array(243, 2), Array(247, 2), _
        Array(255, 2), Array(259, 2), Array(267, 2), Array(271, 2), Array(279, 2), Array(283, 2), _
        Array(290, 2), Array(295, 2), Array(302, 2), Array(307, 2), Array(315, 2), Array(319, 2), _
        Array(327, 2), Array(331, 2), Array(339, 2), Array(343, 2), Array(351, 2), Array(355, 2), _
        Array(363, 2), Array(367, 2), Array(375, 2), Array(379, 2), Array(387, 2), Array(391, 2), _
        Array(399, 2), Array(403, 2), Array(411, 2), Array(415, 2), Array(423, 2), Array(427, 2), _
        Array(435, 2), Array(439, 2), Array(447, 2), Array(451, 2), Array(459, 2), Array(463, 2), _
        Array(471, 2), Array(475, 2), Array(483, 2), Array(487, 2), Array(495, 2), Array(499, 2), _
        Array(507, 2), Array(511, 2), Array(519, 2), Array(523, 2), Array(531, 2), Array(535, 2), _
        Array(543, 2), Array(547, 2), Array(555, 2), Array(559, 2), Array(567, 2), Array(571, 2), _
        Array(579, 2), Array(583, 2), Array(591, 2), Array(595, 2), Array(603, 2), Array(607, 2), _
        Array(615, 2), Array(619, 2), Array(627, 2), Array(631, 2), Array(639, 2), Array(643, 2), _
        Array(651, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like the following

```
Dim mySheet as WorkSheet
Set mySheet = wkb.sheets(mySheet)
Do Until mySheet.Cells(r,c) = ""
  If InStr(mySheet.Cells(r,c), "08") = 1 Then
    Call getDataProperly
  End If
  r = r + 1
Loop
```

This would use `mySheet` as whatever the worksheet in question is, and this could be dynamic with a `For each sheet in Workbook.Sheets` type of scenario.  Then it loops through the rows in this case, but could easily work for columns until it hits an empty cell.  If you need a more defined loop you could use a `For` loop to have it run a set number of iterations.  The trick that makes your call run is the `If InStr(mySheet.Cells(r,c),"08") = 1`  What this does is look for the "08" value and only if that match starts at the first position of the cell you are looking at does the `getDataProperly` sub work.